# Как динамически определять возвращаемый тип метода?

Tags: c#

```
var collection = new ObservableCollection<Node>(CustomAppSettings.LoadElement<Node[]>("Collection") ?? new Node[0]);
```

Метод загрузки элемента

```
public static T LoadElement<T>(string name)
{
    return Settings.ContainsKey(name) ? (T)Settings[name] : default(T);
}
```

Коллекция имеет в перегрузках конструктора типы `IEnumerable<Node>` и `List<Node>`

Как заставить метод возвращать тип, соответствующий типу конструктора? По типу работы Linq.

Например:

```
new ObservableCollection<Node>(CustomAppSettings.LoadElement("Collection") ?? new Node[0]);
```

Comment: о какой коллекции идет речь? что значит _заставить метод возвращать тип, соответствующий типу конструктора_? Какой метод? Пример с Linq - непонятен

Comment: Пример линк: 'var i = new int[] { 0, 5 }; var sum = i.Sum();' Метод суммирования заранее знает что он работает с массивом чисел и выдает результат - число. Как заставить мой метод заранее видеть, что от него ожидают 'IEnumerable<Node>', исходят из контекста конструкторов обс. коллекции

Comment: Всю необходимую информацию добавляй в вопрос, отредактировать его можно с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: _Как заставить мой метод заранее видеть, что от него ожидают 'IEnumerable<Node>', исходят из контекста конструкторов обс. коллекции_ - добавь пример того, как бы ты хотел чтобы это выглядело в итоге

Comment: Пример желаемого в конце поста

Comment: Тогда никак. В твоем случае - это невозможно.

Comment: Незаметна связь между примером в конце вопроса и LINQ. Если ты сможешь показать аналогичный пример из LINQ, то можно будет его подправить под твой случай. Пример с `Sum` в комментарии выше не имеет ничего общего с твоим случаем

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Можно тогда вынести в ответ

Comment: У вас есть коллекция, которая ждет в констукторе именно `List<T>`? Если нет - то ваш код можно свести к возврату именно `IEnumerable<T>`, и заодно убрать лишний код вида `?? new Node[0]`

Comment: @PashaPash, как я понял, автор хочет, чтобы его функция осталась прежней, но в случае, если от нее ждут IEnumerable, Она бы это сама определяла

Comment: Grundy правильно понял. Чтобы на вызове метода самому не определять тип в < > скобках

Comment: Что такое Settings? Откуда Settings знает какая настройка какого типа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На основе строковой константы - **никак**.

Смотрите, вы хотите чтобы вот эти строчки работали одновременно:

```
IEnumerable<Node> list = CustomAppSettings.LoadElement("Collection");
string locale = CustomAppSettings.LoadElement("Locale");
```

Но что будет если передать в метод не константу - а выражение?

```
??? foo = CustomAppSettings.LoadElement(bar ? "Collection" : "Locale")
```

Какого типа должна быть переменная foo? До тех пор пока компилятор не способен ответить на этот вопрос - создать метод LoadElement с нужными вам свойствами будет невозможно.

---

Для сравнения, LINQ для определения типа возвращаемого значения использует тип параметра. Т.е. из одного типа выводится другой тип. А вот выводить тип из строковой константы - в C# нельзя.

Comment: не, по идее он хотел, чтобы вывод типа основывался не только на внутренностях функции, но и на вызываемом коде, то есть, в примере с выражением значение `<T>` должно было как раз зависеть от того, что пользователь напишет вместо `???`

Answer (score -1):

Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос, но может быть это имел ввиду автор?

```
    public static T LoadElement<T>(string name) where T : IEnumerable<Node>
    {
        return Settings.ContainsKey(name) ? (T)Settings[name] : default(T);
    }
```

Comment: `String locale = CustomAppSettings.LoadElement("Locale")` возвращать string.

Comment: Тогда мб вместо string name написать T name?

Comment: Хорошо, как обращаться к словарю в таком случае?

Comment: Никак. Ты же сам сказал, что `CustomAppSettings.LoadElement("Locale")` должен возвращать `string`, а не словарь string'ов

Comment: Settings - словарь <string,object>

Comment: Тогда добавить второй параметр T2 и написать условие where T2 : IEnumerable<Node>?